# Toggling Font Awesome 5 icon with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to toggle a Font Awesome icon by clicking on a to-do list item. Here is the entire component...

```
import React from 'react';

import './TodoItem.scss';

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      complete: false
    }
    this.toggleComplete = this.toggleComplete.bind(this);
  }

  toggleComplete() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      complete: !prevState.complete
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const incompleteIcon = <span className="far fa-circle todo-item-icon"></span>;
    const completeIcon = <span className="far fa-check-circle todo-item-icon"></span>;

    return (
      <div className="todo-item" onClick={this.toggleComplete}>
        {this.state.complete ? completeIcon : incompleteIcon}
        <span className="todo-item-text">{this.props.item}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Here's my FA 5 CDN (straight from the website)...

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
```

I've taken a few screenshots of the React dev tool and inspector...

Here is the React component while incomplete (the default)
[image: React component while incomplete]

And while complete...
[image: React component while complete]

And the two icon elements in the inspector, I noticed the one not being used by default is commented out.
[image]

As you can see, I'm able to manually toggle the complete state and the component changes in the React tool but the change is not rendered. I changed the default state to make sure both icons are loaded correctly and they are. I made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jonathano_/pen/OOKKZd?editors=1010) to try it in a different environment and this one **works, but** I am using the FA 4.7.0 CDN. With the Codepen and FA 4.7.0, when I inspect the icon, it is just an HTML element not SVG.

I'd like to get this component working with FA 5 so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hi, i put your code into a codepen and it seems to work. https://codepen.io/swyx/pen/mqZxoL so it is likely you have some sort of FA loading issue.

Comment: @swyx just tried it myself and it does seem to be a FA issue, the code works in any other case. Is it possible that React won't render it since the only difference between elements is a class and not content? Thanks for helping out, not sure what this is.

Comment: no, you can check that this is the case by putting literally any other class with some styling on the class and see that this is so

Comment: @swyx yea, I hadn't thought of that. oops.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955929/161457

Answer (score 18):

The font-awesome javascript doesn't rerender on a React rerender trigger. If you are okay with not using the new font-awesome svg/javascript icons, you can use font-awesome as a webfont with css.

In your index.html, delete the fontawesome script, and add the font-awesome css stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your code should work now.

---

The other possibility is to use the official font-awesome react package (it's a bit more of a hassle, but it uses the new svg icons)

Add necessary packages to project:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

Example code:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCircle as fasCircle } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
import { faCircle as farCircle } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular'

const Circle = ({ filled, onClick }) => {

  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={filled ? farCircle : fasCircle}/>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { filled: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ filled: !this.state.filled });
  };

  render() {
    return <Circle filled={this.state.filled} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}
```

See the github repo for more information: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

This answer is an edited version of my answer here: [How can I get Font Awesome 5 to work with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954237/how-can-i-get-font-awesome-5-to-work-with-react).

Comment: We're preparing a new version of the react-fontawesome package that is cleaned up and easier to use. The pre-releases are out and you can find documentation in our development branch: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/tree/development

Comment: css can't be the opinion, because it only covers half.

Answer (score 15):

Since FA 5 injects svg elements into the DOM, it probably doesn't play nicely with React's virtual DOM. Hopefully it's something they'll fix, but a simple workaround is to just include both icons instead of toggling them, and hide one or the other by wrapping it in a container that applies `display: none`. For example:

```
renderChatButton() {
  const unread = this.state.unread
  const normalIcon = <i className='far fa-comment' />
  const unreadIcon = <i className='fas fa-comment' />
  return (
    <div className='header-button' onClick={ this.toggleChat }>
      <span className={ unread ? 'hidden' : '' }>{ normalIcon }</span>
      <span className={ unread ? '' : 'hidden' }>{ unreadIcon }</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have to say this is the real cure of this `fontAwesome` issue. Because other solutions always carry a lagging issue, since each call of fetching icon takes time.

Answer (score 2):

as per discussion above this is likely a fontawesome bug, not a react bug

Comment: Not a bug. The SVG with JS just isn't compatible with a virtual DOM engine.

Comment: in a sense, this is a fontawesome "bug", because who  the heck want to make a API call for each icon?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like another fix is to call `window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }` somewhere in your app's boot cycle, after the FA JavaScript has been loaded.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552226/53790 and https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#auto-replace-svg-nest.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today with my ReactJS/Material-UI application. After much research I fixed the issue by using React's `key` property that forces an element to render when its associated state changes.

So, in this example I would rewrite the render method as below:

```
render() {
    const icon = this.state.complete ? (<span key={this.state.complete} className="far fa-circle todo-item-icon"/>) : (<span key={this.state.complete} className="far fa-check-circle todo-item-icon"/>);

    return (
      <div className="todo-item" onClick={this.toggleComplete}>
        {icon}
        <span className="todo-item-text">{this.props.item}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here I've used `this.state.complete` as unique value for the `key` but you could use anything you like so long as they are unique.

Now, the `span` element is always removed on re-render and replaced by the other one.

Hope this answer helps future seekers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to function instead of class but before this you need to downlaod the react fontawesome package for reactjs code:

```
    import React from  'react';
    import Menuitems from '././Menuitems';
    import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
    import { faTimes, faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    
    const Menu =() => {
    
       const [item, setItem]= React.useState(false);
    
       const handleitem =()=>{
         setItem(!true);
       }
        return(
            <>
              <Container>
                  <nav>
                       <h1> react </h1>
                 
                     <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleitem}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={item ? faTimes :  faBars } size="3x"/>
                     </div>
                  </nav>
               </Container>
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Menu;
```