# How can I get Font Awesome 5 to work with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

In the following example, the initial icon renders but it does not change when the class changes.

```js
const Circle = ({ filled, onClick }) => {
  const className = filled ? 'fas fa-circle' : 'far fa-circle';
  
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} >
      <i className={className} />
      <p>(class is {className})</p>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { filled: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ filled: !this.state.filled });
  };
  
  render() {
    return <Circle filled={this.state.filled} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BO41 is right, it is the font-awesome javascript that doesn't rerender. If you are okay with not using the new font-awesome svg/javascript icons, you can use font-awesome as a webfont with css.

In your index.html, delete the fontawesome script, and add the font-awesome css stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your code should work now.

---

The other possibility is to use the official font-awesome react package (it's a bit more of a hassle, but it uses the new svg icons)

Add necessary packages to project:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

And the updated code:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCircle as fasCircle } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
import { faCircle as farCircle } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular'

const Circle = ({ filled, onClick }) => {

  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={filled ? farCircle : fasCircle}/>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { filled: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ filled: !this.state.filled });
  };

  render() {
    return <Circle filled={this.state.filled} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}
```

See the github repo for more information: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

Comment: You might want to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707306/toggling-font-awesome-5-icon-with-react as well - the questions are similar (I'll let others decide if one should be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: I submitted my answer there as well, thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure fontawesome to nest the svg inside a `<i>` tag. This way react can rerender it.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

> Nest  tags instead of replacing There may be some cases where the
>   replacement of the  tag is just not working out like you need it
>   to.
>
> You can configure Font Awesome to nest the  within the  tag.
>
> We start with an i tag

```
<script>
  FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }
</script>
<i class="my-icon fas fa-coffee" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle"></i>
```

> And end up with an svg tag inside the original i

```
<i class="my-icon" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle" data-fa-i2svg="">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-coffee fa-w-16" data-fa-mask="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-fa-i2svg="" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="coffee" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">...</svg>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to re-trigger the font awesome javascript to render the new icon. If you would use a real image with  tag it would work like you intended

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I am sorry. But I only used the css version. You would have to look through the js source code and see if there is a method to rerender everything. Otherwise I don't think you got a chance besides reloading the page. (maybe place an iframe just for the icon and reload this)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I believe that can be solved by using the `key` attribute:

```
  <div key={Math.random()} onClick={onClick} >
      <i className={className} />
      <p>(class is {className})</p>
  </div>
```

this will force react to update your div, then you will have the expected behavior and keep using the library as you were ;