# Font awesome 5: icon not switching when condition changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm using font awesome 5 in a react.js project, and having trouble make the icon switch in a conditional statement. Here's the sample code:

```
!isRecording
&&
<div style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.record(e)}>
    <span className="fa-layers  fa-4x">
      <div><i className="fas fa-circle " style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
      <div><i className="fa fa-microphone  fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
||
<div style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.stop(e)}>
    <span className="fa-layers  fa-4x">
      <div><i className="fas fa-circle " style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
      <div><i className="fas fa-stop  fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

When `isRecording == true`, the icon should change from `fa-microphone` to `fa-stop`. But the switch doesn't happen. The microphone icon stays.

Strangely, when I don't use the `fa-layers` class in the button to be switched in, the switch happens. But the transition is super awkward--icon size and position shift:

```
!isRecording
&&
<div style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.record(e)}>
    <span className="fa-layers  fa-4x">
      <div><i className="fas fa-circle " style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
      <div><i className={isRecording ? `fa fa-stop  fa-inverse` : `fa fa-microphone  fa-inverse`} data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
||
<div style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.stop(e)}>
    <span className=" fa-2x">
      <div key="stopRecord"><i className="fa fa-stop-circle fa-2x" style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experimented around with your code and realized that you are using FontAwesome's new SVG JavaScript library which completely explains the problem. The code that that library uses to look at the DOM and insert the icons doesn't play well with React. This is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955929/6662225).

To solve this problem, you can either ...

- use [the "old-school" CSS version of FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css) and shrink the icon manually using CSS
- or use [FontAwesome's official React component](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome)

Comment: This is it. Changed to the font awesome react component and it's now working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't **duplicate** code for **little changement**.

If you just have to change a class/content use an expression in your `className`

And change your called method in `onClick` to check the state of `isRecording`to call the right method (`stop/record`)

```js
handleMicroClick(e){
  this.state.isRecording ? this.stop(e) : this.record(e);
}
```

```html
<div style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => handleMicroClick(e)}>
     <span className="fa-layers  fa-4x">
        <div>
            <i className="fas fa-circle " style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}>               </i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i className={isRecording ? 'fa-microphone' : 'fa-stop'} data-fa-transform="shrink-6">
            </i>
        </div>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexis unfortunately this approach does not work. It would show the microphone button when `isRecording == false`, but it wouldn't switch to stop button when the condition changes.

Comment: I can 100% guarantee you that when you correctly update the `isRecording` property of your state object using `setState`, the icon will change. The problem must lie somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @NiklasHigi I can 100% guarantee you that the state of `isRecording` is being changed with no problem. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @NatashaC Do you use the state to uptate your variable ? (`this.state.isRecording`)

Comment: @Alexis yes I use `setState`. As the state does change. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I also have the same issue and solved without using the proposed alternatives.

You can make use of `key` property, forcing React to update your component

```
!isRecording
&&
<div key={Math.random()} style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.record(e)}>
    <span className="fa-layers  fa-4x">
      <div><i className="fas fa-circle " style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
      <div><i className={isRecording ? `fa fa-stop  fa-inverse` : `fa fa-microphone  fa-inverse`} data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
||
<div key={Math.random()} style={styles.recordButton} onClick={e => this.stop(e)}>
    <span className=" fa-2x">
      <div key="stopRecord"><i className="fa fa-stop-circle fa-2x" style={{color: Colors.mainOrange}}></i></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then it works as expected ;)