# Dynamically change icon in angular 6

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am trying to change the `font-awesome` icon depending on a certain value but it stays set to the original icon even after my model has changed. Here is my code

In `Controller`

```
if (foo.change < 0) {
   foo.icon = "fa fa-sort-down";
} else {
  foo.icon = "fas fa-sort-up";
}
```

In my `HTML`

```
<i [className]="foo.icon"></i>
```

Is there a way to update an icon dynamically based on a `model` or a `check`?

Comment: Are you sure that `foo.icon` is updated all the time when there is a change on `foo.change`?

Comment: Yeah i have stepped through it and each time it has been updated but the icon did not change i have also tried doing <i class="col"
                                                [className]="foo.change > 0 ? 'fas fa-caret-up' : 'fas fa-caret-down'"></i>

Comment: I have a field that displays the value of the foo.change so i can see it when it changes

Comment: Mayby its something with font awesome, add two simple temp css classes, ex: .test1{color:red}; .test2{color:green} and see it they work. you would need to add some temp content in the <i>

Comment: I am able to change the color of the text and the font by doing this <div [className]="foo.change > 0? 'text-success': 'text-danger'" class="row"> but for some reason the fonts do not change

Comment: Can you add a static font awesome image? <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>

Comment: If you can. Then its something with you class='row'. Try to do the same [ngClass] somewhere else. Outside the 'row' element

Comment: I can see the font, it shows up but the issue is it does not change to fas fa-caret-up when my value goes above zero or change to fas fa-caret-down when my value goes below zero, it stays the same as the initial set icon

Comment: Should it not be [ngClass]?

Comment: please share the stackblitz or plunker link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1069400/fontawesome-icon-is-not-changing-after-toggling-its-class-with-jquery-where-am-i-doing-it-wrong) online:

> The error is due to the fontawesome JS library wich dynamically
>   replace the elements defined with specific classes by svg elements
>   sharing attributes of the initial element, so you cannot use the
>   element tag name to select it: you need to select the new svg created
>   element by another way

So, the simplest solution would be:

```
<i *ngIf="foo.change < 0" [className]="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
<i *ngIf="foo.change >= 0" [className]="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
```

Comment: This is the reason! I will figure out a work around thanks!

Answer (score 6):

use [ngClass]

```
<i  [ngClass]="foo.change < 0 ? 'fa fa-sort-down' : 'fas fa-sort-up'"></i>
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same result, it seems because font awesome is creating svg elements they do not get removed from the dom

Comment: @inhaler - This answer works fine with a simple test on stackblitz. There must be something else going wrong in your component maybe.

Comment: I will create a stackblitz and try it out

Comment: I could not get it to work i used the font awesome template still trying to figure out how to share it

Comment: If you where able to get it to work please could you share with me

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not legit (clean) technical way to do it, but I would place two fa fa icons in different DIVs, while one is hidden. And than switch hidden property on click with a little JavaScript function. Depends on how far your JavaScript skill goes, you could combine some loops, counters etc and make anything works.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="up">
 <button onclick="myFunction()">
  Sort <i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
 </button>
</div>
<div id="down" hidden>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">
  Sort <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
 </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(){
 var up = document.getElementById('up');
 var down = document.getElementById('down');
 
 if (down.hidden == true){
  down.hidden = false;
  up.hidden = true;
 } else {
  down.hidden = true;
  up.hidden = false;
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<i class="pi" [ngClass]="{'true-icon pi-check-circle': dataEithertrueOrFalse, 'false-icon pi-times-circle': !dataEithertrueOrFalse}"></i>
```

If you want to change the style dynamically you can create a function (here i created with the name function Color for which input is dataEithertrueOrFalse).

```
<i class="pi" [style.color]="function_Color(dataEithertrueOrFalse)" [ngClass]="{'true-icon pi-check-circle': dataEithertrueOrFalse, 'false-icon pi-times-circle': !dataEithertrueOrFalse}"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wandering about this issue, the solution is to use angular font awesome. Check out the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755509/font-awesome-5-icon-not-switching-when-condition-changes)

I was able to get this to work using angular font awesome [link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular)