# Change to React State doesn't update display in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple, 2 component app where the name of the animal shows the icon of the animal to generalize an issue I am having in a more complicated app.

Once a random animal is selected and merged into `state`, the `Display` component should re-render, and the `animalIcon` should also update, since `state`is being pass down through `props` (or so I thought).

Instead, we are stuck on icon of whatever the first animal is (randomly chosen).

I would really like to know why the icon doesn't update, since I thought when `state` is changed, it will re-render the components that use that piece of information (in this case, the `Display` component), and `console.log(animalIcon)` is correctly showing me that on every re-render of the `Display` component, that the `animalIcon` is correctly being assigned the right element/icon.

**The only thing not changing is the output of `{animalIcon}` in the `return` statement of the `Display` component.**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentAnimal: ''
    }
    this.getAnimal = this.getAnimal.bind(this);
  }
  
  getAnimal() {
    
    function getRandomAnimal(arr) {
      function getRandomIndex(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
      
      return arr[getRandomIndex(0, arr.length - 1)];
    }
    
      const allAnimals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'];
      const chosenAnimal = getRandomAnimal(allAnimals);
      this.setState({currentAnimal: chosenAnimal});
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <Display getAnimal={this.getAnimal} animal={this.state.currentAnimal}/>
    )
  }
}

function Display (props) {
  const icons = {
    cat: <i class="fas fa-cat"></i>,
    dog: <i class="fas fa-dog"></i>,
    mouse: <i class="fas fa-mouse-pointer"></i>,
  }
  
  let animalIcon = icons[props.animal.toLowerCase()];
  console.log(animalIcon);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.animal} looks like {animalIcon}</h1>
      <button onClick={props.getAnimal}>Get New Animal</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="root"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Font Awesome 5 to work with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954237/how-can-i-get-font-awesome-5-to-work-with-react)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I never would've thought that it would be Font Awesome that would be the issue. This is the actual solution I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `animalIcon` with attribute [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) , as you are passing props it seems its not updating correctly. This will tell react to update the icon if animal name is changed.

```
<span key={props.animal}>{
      animalIcon
    }</span>
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentAnimal: ''
    }
    this.getAnimal = this.getAnimal.bind(this);
  }

  getAnimal() {

    function getRandomAnimal(arr) {
      function getRandomIndex(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }

      return arr[getRandomIndex(0, arr.length - 1)];
    }

    const allAnimals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'];
    const chosenAnimal = getRandomAnimal(allAnimals);
    this.setState({
      currentAnimal: chosenAnimal
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      Display getAnimal = {
        this.getAnimal
      }
      animal = {
        this.state.currentAnimal
      }
      />
    )
  }
}

function Display(props) {
  const icons = {
    cat: < i class = "fas fa-cat" > < /i>,
    dog: < i class = "fas fa-dog" > < /i>,
    mouse: < i class = "fas fa-mouse-pointer" > < /i>,
  }

  let animalIcon = icons[props.animal.toLowerCase()];
  console.log(props.animal);

  return ( <div ><h1> {
      props.animal
    }
    looks like <span key={props.animal}>{
      animalIcon
    }</span> < /h1> <
    button onClick = {
      props.getAnimal
    } > Get New Animal < /button> <
    /div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector('.root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="root"></div>
```