# Toggling font awesome Icon using React

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggle a fontAwesome icon class name on click. When clicked, the icon should change the color and also call a service which adds an object to a favorite list in the server (hence, why I use e.currentTarget: I need to remember which icon was clicked).  This code works on the first click, but fails to change the class back on the second click (doing an inspect, it says the FA´s classname equals "Object object"). Any idea how I could fix it?

```
    <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={this.ToggleClass} size={"sm"} icon={faHeart} />

    ToggleClass = (e) => {
      const heart = {
        color: "#E4002B",
      }

      const clicked = {
        color: "#E4002B",
        background: "red"
      }

      if (e.currentTarget.className.baseVal != heart && e.currentTarget.className.baseVal != clicked) {
        return e.currentTarget.className.baseVal === clicked;
#Callservicehere
      }
      else if (e.currentTarget.className.baseVal === clicked) {
        e.currentTarget.className.baseVal = heart;
#callservicehere
      }
    }
```

Comment: Lets see `ToggleClass` definition.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the name when pasting. Please see updated version.

Comment: Its a bit of a overkill using e.currentTarget. You could just create class in css instead of variables for css and toggle state when clicked. Toggle the icon based on state. you can look at this link [toggle icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707306/toggling-font-awesome-5-icon-with-react)

Comment: That doesn´t work because I have several icons, and I want to use only one method. Hence the e.currentTarget

Comment: Every time the function is called you create new objects, so the comparison is never true. The "old" object is never the same as the "new" object, even if it contains the same elements.

Comment: How am I creating a new object?

Comment: I don't think you really understand how `==`, `!=` and `===` works in Javascript. Hint, it doesn't do a deep comparison of objects. And this is not the way to change rendered values in react. Also, your code assigns only `heart`, it never assigns `clicked`.

Comment: Every time you do e.g. `const heart = {
        color: "#E4002B",
      }` you create a new object.

Answer (score 3):

You're not thinking in React yet :)

Accessing the event target and imperatively manipulating the DOM bypasses React's rendering - you might as well just be using jQuery. Not that there's anything bad about that, but it's not the right way to go about things in React.

In React, if you need to change the DOM in response to user interaction you do it in the render method, i.e. output different JSX based on the component's current state or props.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things that might help here:

1. `clicked` and `heart` are both objects which means that you cannot compare them without using a deep comparison method.

```
var a = { id: 1 }
var b = { id: 1 }

console.log(a == b)    //false
console.log(a === b)   //false
```

2. If you want to compare them, you can convert them both to strings using the `toString()` method

```
heart.toString() === clicked.toString()
```

3. In your first `if` condition, it looks like you're returning a true/false value instead of assigning a desired classname to your target.

```
return e.currentTarget.className.baseVal === clicked // true/false


e.currentTarget.className.baseVal = clicked // assigned
```

4. You could also take the approach of keeping your classnames as strings and adding your styled objects inside of css

```
class MysteryComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    className: 'heart'
  }

  toggleClass = (e) => {
    if (this.state.className === 'heart') {
      this.setState({ className: 'clicked' })
    } else if (this.state.className === 'clicked') {
      this.setState({ className: 'heart' })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.className}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={this.toggleClass} size={"sm"} icon={faHeart} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// css 
.heart {
  color: "#E4002B";
}

.clicked {
  color: "#E4002B";
  background: "red";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I have MANY icons which call a service that add that particular item to a favorite list. So remembering WHICH icon was clicked is important. This code will fill ALL icons, which isn´t really what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I see. You want to fill/unfill the color of the heart as the user clicks. The reason why the results are not meeting your expectations is because of the event.targets are especially funky with FontAwesome. You may think you're clicking on it, but it manipulates the DOM in a way that when you try extract the className, it's value is often inconsistent.

This is why everyone is recommending that you make use of React's state. The logic that determines how elements are styled is now more controlled by the component itself instead of the FontAwesome library. Consider the code below, we only care about whether the item was clicked, not what class it initially has.

```
class Example extends React.Component{
    state = {
        clicked: false
    }

    handleOnCLick = () => {
        this.setState({
            clicked: !this.state.clicked
        })
    }

    render(){

        var clicked = this.state.clicked

        return(
        <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            <i
                class={ clicked ? "fas fa-heart" : "fas fa-circle"}
            </i>
        </button>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I have MANY icons which call a service that add that particular item to a favorite list. So remembering WHICH icon was clicked is important. This code will fill ALL icons, which isn´t really what I want.

Comment: You could employ multiple pieces of state, to keep track of that though.